# Jumping between braces not working in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to jump to the closing brace for any open brace in a valid SQL which has subqueries, using ctrl+]. It's not doing anything. The key combo seems to be mapped correctly. Using SSMS 17.3.

Any adeas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you don't need to hold down the `shift` key?
from [SSMS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts)

```
Text Selection Keyboard Shortcuts
Action                 SQL Server 2017                SQL Server 2008 R2
Move the cursor to the next brace, extending the selection  
                       CTRL+SHIFT+]                   No equivalent
```

and

```
Microsoft IntelliSense Keyboard Shortcuts
Action                      SQL Server 2017 SQL Server 2008 R2
Jump between syntax pairs   CTRL+]          CTRL+]
```

take a look under `tools/options/text editor/all languages/general/settings (lower) section/Automatic Brace completion`.  Mine was filled in solid instead of checked.
May not affect what you want, but may have some conflict dependent on the setting.
Also, under the Transact-SQL language, the `automatic brace completion` option is disabled.  Not sure if the settings are related.

Comment: Holding down ctrl-shift-] or ctrl-] don't do anything. Does it work for you?

Comment: it does, but only if my cursor is before the open paren.  It may also be an issue of scale (works with fewer parens or levels of nesting or lines of code.)  Can you post the code that doesn't work for you?
Actually, I'm using an older version of SSMS, let me try upgrading

Comment: it's working for me with small sets of code, can you upload what's not working for you or try what you have in an earlier version and confirm the problem's with the version of SSMS?